# SAT mathematics. Level 2. Trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

The answer is 3 and 5. Explanation?[image]

Comment: This is a triangle with three knowns which are in counter-clockwise order: Side-Side-Angle.  You should know that there are generally two possibilities (either in this case $\angle ABC >\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\angle ABC<\frac{\pi}{2}$).  Check any elementary textbook on trigonometry or "algebra 2" (highschool algebra, not abstract algebra) or websites such as [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-ssa-triangles.html) for how to solve for the remaining unknowns of a triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $BC=x$. By the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

$$7^2=8^2+x^2-2\cdot 8\cdot x\cdot \cos\frac{\pi}{3}$$

$\cos\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$, so

$$\iff x^2-8x+15=0\iff (x-4)^2=1$$

$$\iff x-4=\pm 1\iff x\in\{3,5\}$$

Answer (score 1):

For SAT2 math, you ought to memorize both the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) and the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines). They're both useful to rapidly solve problems with non-right triangles. This one uses the Law of Cosines, where $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle with opposing angles $A,B,C$.

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ac\cos C$$

In your case,

$$7^2 = 8^2 + x^2 -2(8)(x)\cos \frac{\pi}{3}$$

You can either solve this as a quadratic equation (preferably) or substitute your answer choices to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Draw perpendicular from point B to AC, you will get two right angle triangles.

I will leave rest of the work to consider self.